# Google Apps Script: Read rtf value from API and paste as formatted text into Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, rtf

I am using Google Apps Script to fetch rich text in the following form:

```
{"blocks":[{"key":"dgn8a","text":"This Text is rich.","type":"unstyled","depth":0,"inlineStyleRanges":[{"offset":0,"length":4,"style":"ITALIC"},{"offset":13,"length":4,"style":"ITALIC"},{"offset":0,"length":4,"style":"BOLD"},{"offset":5,"length":4,"style":"UNDERLINE"}],"entityRanges":[],"data":{}}],"entityMap":{}}
```

and I would like to paste this text in the correct format to a Google sheet.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Comment: Try creating a richTextValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have the metadata object of converted rich texts with [draft-js](https://github.com/facebookarchive/draft-js).
- You want to put your object to cells of the Spreadsheet as the rich text.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // This is from your question.
  const obj = { "blocks": [{ "key": "dgn8a", "text": "This Text is rich.", "type": "unstyled", "depth": 0, "inlineStyleRanges": [{ "offset": 0, "length": 4, "style": "ITALIC" }, { "offset": 13, "length": 4, "style": "ITALIC" }, { "offset": 0, "length": 4, "style": "BOLD" }, { "offset": 5, "length": 4, "style": "UNDERLINE" }], "entityRanges": [], "data": {} }], "entityMap": {} };

  // Convert from your object to rich text for a Spreadsheet.
  const convStyles = { "BOLD": "setBold", "ITALIC": "setItalic", "UNDERLINE": "setUnderline" };
  const richTextValues = obj.blocks.map(({ inlineStyleRanges, text }) => {
    const temp = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(text);
    inlineStyleRanges.forEach(({ offset, length, style }) =>
      temp.setTextStyle(offset, offset + length, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()[convStyles[style]](true).build())
    );
    return [temp.build()];
  });

  // Put rich text to the cells.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, richTextValues.length).setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is a simple sample script for understanding the script and converting your provided object to rich text for the Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. So, when you want to use other styles, please modify the above script.

#### References:

- [Class TextStyle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style)
- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)
- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)

Comment: Perfect! That helps a lot! The rest should be no problem, as the draft-js editor, the rich text is coming from, seems to be quite limited.

Comment: @Gardinero Thank you for replying and testing it. I understood your situation. And, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.